# Custom EF Core AddOrUpdate with composite keys

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core, composite-primary-key, any

I've built an extension for `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` that implements the `AddOrUpdateMethod`. It's working fine, but with entities with a composite primary key the `AnyAsync` method return always false, even if there are objects with the same key.

This is the method:

```
public static async Task AddOrUpdateAsync<TEntity>(this DbSet<TEntity> table, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> key, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> deleteExpression, params TEntity[] entities) where TEntity : class
{
    var getKeyFunction = key.Compile();
    var getShouldDeleteFunction = deleteExpression.Compile();
    var context = GetDbContext(table);
    foreach (var entity in entities)
    {
        var primaryKey = getKeyFunction(entity);
        var body = Expression.Equal(Expression.Convert(key.Body, primaryKey.GetType()), Expression.Constant(primaryKey));
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> query = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, key.Parameters);
        var exist = await table.AnyAsync(query);
        context.Entry(entity).State = exist
            ? getShouldDeleteFunction(entity) ? EntityState.Deleted : EntityState.Modified
            : getShouldDeleteFunction(entity) ? EntityState.Detached : EntityState.Added;
    }
}

private static DbContext GetDbContext<T>(this DbSet<T> table) where T : class
{
    var infrastructure = table as IInfrastructure<IServiceProvider>;
    var serviceProvider = infrastructure.Instance;
    var currentDbContext = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(ICurrentDbContext)) as ICurrentDbContext;
    return currentDbContext.Context;
}
```

and I'm using it like this:

```
await db.Reports.AddOrUpdateAsync(r => new { r.Number, r.Year }, r => r.Active == false, response.Reports.ToArray());
```

I think that's happening because I'm using an anonymous type as the key, but I've no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be the usage of the anonymous type constant expression, which currently is causing [client evaluation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/client-eval#client-evaluation), and C# operator `==` compares anonymous types by reference, hence always returns `false`.

The trick to get the desired server translation is to "invoke" the `key` expression with `entity` by replacing the parameter with `Expression.Constant(entity)` (`Expression.Invoke` doesn't work in this case)

So remove the line `var getKeyFunction = key.Compile();` as no longer needed, and use the following:

```
foreach (var entity in entities)
{
    var parameter = key.Parameters[0];
    var body = Expression.Equal(
        key.Body,
        key.Body.ReplaceParameter(parameter, Expression.Constant(entity))
    );
    var query = Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(body, parameter);
    var exist = await table.AnyAsync(query);
    // ...
}
```

where `ReplaceParameter` is the usual expression helper method:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
        => new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            => node == Source ? Target : node;
    }
}
```